# ASP.NET Page naming using master pages

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

I have two user types: Readers and Authors. And I'm using `Reader.Master` and `Author.Master` for authorization purposes.

Then, there are `StoriesR.aspx` inherited from `Reader.Master` and `StoriesA.aspx` inherited from `Author.Master`. (In `StoriesR.aspx` page, you able to read the stories and in `StoriesA.aspx` you able to write the story.) So,

1. `Reader.Master` --> `StoriesR.aspx`
2. `Author.Master` --> `StoriesA.aspx`

Now, the thing is I don't want my users to see `StoriesR.aspx?s=3` or `StoriesA.aspx?s=3` in their browsers. I only want them to see `stories?s=3`. (even without the `.aspx` part)

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

you can do this using urlMappings from web.config file

add in web.confing

```
<system.web>
    <!-- 
        Set compilation debug="true" to insert debugging 
        symbols into the compiled page. Because this 
        affects performance, set this value to true only 
        during development.
    -->
    <urlMappings enabled="true">
        <add url="~/reader/stories" mappedUrl="~/reader/StoriesR.aspx"/>
        <add url="~/author/stories" mappedUrl="~/author/StoriesA.aspx"/>
```

This will do url mapping.

Comment: i don't want to use "~/reader/stories" and "~/author/stories" in my query string either.

Answer (score 1):

You could have one aspx page and change the master page programmatically depending on what type of user they are, Author or Reader.

You can do this in the `Page_PreInit` event of your aspx page.

Check [this c# example](http://frejnorling.wordpress.com/2011/01/26/master-pages-in-asp-net-programmatically-change-master-page/) or [this VB example](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/master-pages/specifying-the-master-page-programmatically-vb)